# How to make horizontal spacing between div elements

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a simple drawing program and I'm having trouble making some spaces between my drawing canvas and buttons & colors (pickers). I just want to ask if there is any way to space them properly? I tried just to `<br>` the lines but it's restricting my drawing area for some reason. I also tried bordering it and making the border transparent but it didn't work. Any tips?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth = 650;
canvas.height = 350;

let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let draw_color = "black";
let draw_width = "2";
let is_drawing = false;

canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mtouchstart", stop, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);


function start(event) {
  is_drawing = true;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
    event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);

  event.preventDefault();
}

function draw(event) {
  if (is_drawing) {
    context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
      event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
    context.strokeStyle = draw_color;
    context.lineWidth = draw_width;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.stroke();
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}

function stop(event) {
  if (is_drawing) {
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    is_drawing = false;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
  body,
a,
a:hover {
  cursor: url('https://66.media.tumblr.com/7659e714cab33f9d59124f924405e793/tumblr_inline_p7g82dZq1h1r466gz_75sq.png'), auto
}

body {
  background-image: url('img_girl.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  padding: 5px
}

.tools .color-field {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.color-field {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.tools {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.tools .button {
  align-self: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background: #DB7093;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.color-picker {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.pen-range {
  align-self: center;
  margin: o 15px;
  background-color: #DB7093;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 425px;
```

```html
<head>
  <img src="logo.png" style="width:50%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: 400px; ">
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('https://images8.alphacoders.com/105/1055726.png');">


  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> cute drawing program </title>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="status" style="color: white;"></div>
    <img src="container.png" style="width:120%;">
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>

    <div class="tools">
      <button type="button" class="button"> Undo </button>
      <button type="button" class="button"> Clear </button>


      <div class="color-field" style="background: red;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: blue;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: yellow;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: green;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: orange;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: pink;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: brown;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: gray;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: black;"></div>
      <div class="color-field" style="background: white;"></div>

      <input type="color" class="color-picker">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="pen-range">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? To put buttons on one row and color pickers on other or?

Comment: I just want to make more space between the drawing canvas and all the colors displayed bellow.

Comment: While I've edited your posted code to turn it into a runnable "[Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/82548)", and you're missing a trailing `}` from your CSS. This is unlikely to be your problem, but beyond moving JavaScript and CSS into the relevant areas of the editor I've chosen to not fix your code. Please take a look and make sure it reproduces your problem behaviour, and roll-back your original version if you wish. (Also, while I don't think it should be there at all I did leave the `<img>` in the `<head>`.)

Answer (score 1):

on your .tools, change margin top

```
.tools {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top:  15px; /* <- change this number */
}
```

you may also want to remove the margin-top: 200px; on your .canvas because it's breaking it

Think your design as boxes inside boxes, one thing I do is to set up a background color to better visualize where is a box and where is the other so I can fix their positions, when I'm done, I just put the color back to normal.

I also suggest getting started with flex, here is a fun game to learn flex, I started with this too :) https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
Hopefully it works! 
Here is link which provided
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/yLMzEXE)

```js
 const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth = 650;
    canvas.height = 350;

    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    let draw_color = "black";
    let draw_width = "2";
    let is_drawing = false;

    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mtouchstart", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);


    function start(event) {
        is_drawing = true;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);

    event.preventDefault();
    }

function draw(event) {
    if ( is_drawing ) {
        context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
        context.strokeStyle = draw_color;
        context.lineWidth = draw_width;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.stroke();
    }

    event.preventDefault();
}

function stop(event) {
    if (is_drawing) {
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        is_drawing = false;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body, a, a:hover { cursor:url('https://66.media.tumblr.com/7659e714cab33f9d59124f924405e793/tumblr_inline_p7g82dZq1h1r466gz_75sq.png'), auto 
}

body {
    background-image: url('img_girl.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

canvas {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 5px;

}


.tools .color-field {
    height:  40px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor:  pointer;
    display:  inline-block;
    box-sizing:  border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    align-self:  center;
    margin: 5px 5px ;

}


.color-field {

    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.tools {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top:  15px;
}

.tools .button{
    align-self:  center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    cursor:  pointer;
    color: white;
    background: #DB7093;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:  0 10px;
    display: block;

}


.button {

    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.color-picker {
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: pink;
}

.pen-range {
    align-self:  center;
    margin:  o 15px;
    background-color: #DB7093;

}


.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  margin-left:  425px;
}

/* Added */
.canvas {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your html which are creating unexpected results.

On top of that, there is a lot of CSS that doesn't quite add up.

I recommend checking out the free tutorials and documentation on [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/) to get a stronger grasp on HTML, specifically structure-wise.

Here is an example of what I *assume* you are going for, with some major additions to the HTML structure.

To answer your initial question, using `position: fixed;` along with setting the now fixed position to `left:0;` and `bottom:0` to make the "tools" div a sticky at the bottom of the page.

To keep the canvas in the center without affecting the tools section and visa-versa,
I went ahead and applied `position:relative;` along with a vertical position of +48px against the top of the parent element, this way your header, "container", now centered as well with `margin: 0 auto;`, will be centered and clearly displayed at the top.

The main thing you should take from this is that checking out some tutorials on HTML structure will help you greatly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
<head>

    <!--META-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cute Drawing Program</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A cute drawing app!">
    <meta src="logo.png" alt="a logo!">

    <style>

    body, a, a:hover { cursor:url('https://66.media.tumblr.com/7659e714cab33f9d59124f924405e793/tumblr_inline_p7g82dZq1h1r466gz_75sq.png'), auto}

    body {
        background-image: url('img_girl.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }



    canvas {
        position: relative;
        top: 48px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }


    .tools .color-field {
        height:  40px;
        width: 40px;
        cursor:  pointer;
        display:  inline-block;
        box-sizing:  border-box;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 2px solid white;
        align-self:  center;
        margin: 5px 5px ;

    }


    .color-field {

        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }


    .tools {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .tools .button{
        align-self:  center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        cursor:  pointer;
        color: white;
        background: #DB7093;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin:  0 10px;
        display: block;

    }


    .button {

        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }


    .color-picker {
        align-self: center;
        margin: 0 15px;
        background-color: pink;
    }

    .pen-range {
        align-self:  center;
        margin:  o 15px;
        background-color: #DB7093;
    }

    .container {
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: absolute;
        z-index:-1;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<!--END HEAD TAG-->

<!--BEGIN BODY TAG-->
<body style="background-image: url('https://images8.alphacoders.com/105/1055726.png');">

<div class="container">
  <div id="status" style="color: white;"></div>

      <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
        <img src="container.png">
      </div>

</div>

<div class="field">

    <canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>

    <div class="tools">

        <button type="button" class="button"> Undo </button>
        <button type="button" class="button"> Clear </button>

        <div class="color-field" style="background: red;"></div>
        <div class="color-field" style="background: blue;"></div>
        <div class="color-field" style="background: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="color-field" style="background: green;"></div>
        <div class="color-field" style="background: orange;"></div>
        <div class="color-field" style="background: pink;"></div>
        <div class="color-field" style="background: brown;"></div>
        <div class="color-field" style="background: gray;"></div>   
        <div class="color-field" style="background: black;"></div>
        <div class="color-field" style="background: white;"></div>

        <input type="color" class="color-picker">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" class="pen-range">

    </div>

</div>

<script>
    
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth = 650;
    canvas.height = 350;

    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    let draw_color = "black";
    let draw_width = "2";
    let is_drawing = false;

    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("mtouchstart", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);


    function start(event) {
        is_drawing = true;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);

    event.preventDefault();
    }

function draw(event) {
    if ( is_drawing ) {
        context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
        context.strokeStyle = draw_color;
        context.lineWidth = draw_width;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.stroke();
    }

    event.preventDefault();
}

function stop(event) {
    if (is_drawing) {
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        is_drawing = false;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hostinfodev/pen/mdWBKQW)